# Wrapping text in environment vimtex

Tags: filetype-tex, plugin-vimtex

I use vimtex although I am by no means an expert in Vim, so it may be that I'm missing something obvious. Anyway, I am looking for functionality similar to that of 'cse, csc, csd' (which change the surrounding environment, command, or delimiter respectively) where instead of changing something I would like to add an environment, command, or delimiter around some text highlighted in say visual mode.

The place I find myself most often needing this is when I quickly import a graphic and then have to go back and wrap the command in a center environment. This also sometimes comes up when I have a variable say t which I've forgotten to drop in math mode (so it appears as a non-math t). It's a pain to do `insert mode -> $ -> exit insert mode -> l -> insert mode -> $' and I'm sure there is an easier way, but I haven't been able to find it.

There were a couple of good suggestions on a post I made at the LaTeX stack exchange, but was told to come here for something more official.

Comment: VimTeX does not really have this built in, except for the `<plug>(vimtex-cmd-create)` mapping (default mapped to F7) which works similar to what you ask for for commands. I believe plugins like surround.vim or vim-sandwich and snippet plugins like UltiSnips are better tools for this feature.

Comment: Hi Karl, thanks for the input! I indeed have had good luck with using surround as suggested. Also, I'm sure you get this a lot, but thanks so much for keeping vimtex updated!

Comment: Thanks for using it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using vim-surround from tpope, there are the following:

- `ys<TARGET>l` or `ys<TARGET>l` will prompt for a `\begin{` environment
- `ys<TARGET>$` will surround with dollar-signs

You can also use `S` in visual mode, along with other keys as shown in `:help surround`.

Comment: It looks like the visual mode functionality I was requesting is also a feature (using S). I think that would be a good addition to the answer!

Comment: @Lockjaw added. The help is great for this stuff